# Storing localStorage data as part of rxjs reducer?

Tags: typescript, angular-2+, state

I use `ngrx` in my Angular app to state management. At a certain time I was asked to save some variable to local storage and retrieve it with first load.
That made sense to make it as part of the effects, instead of managing one logic for localStorage and another logic for the selectors. So this is what I did;

I extended ngrx `Action` class as following:

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export class StorableAction implements Action {
    type: string;
    payload?: any;
    localStorageKey?: string;
}
```

Implemented it in the actions (`snapshots.actions.ts`):

```
export class ChangeResolutionWidth implements StorableAction {
    public readonly type = ESnapshotsActionType.ChangeResolutionWidth;
    public readonly localStorageKey = LocalStorageKey.SnapshotsResolutionWidth;

    constructor(public payload: number) { }
}
```

Then in `snapshots.effects.ts`:

```
constructor(
    private channelsService: ChannelsService,
    private actions$: Actions,
    private store: Store<SnapshotsState>
) {
  this.actions$.subscribe(
    (action: StorableAction) => {
      if (action.localStorageKey && action.payload){
        localStorage.setItem(action.localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(action.payload));
      }
    })
  }
```

Now, whenever I load a component, I do `this.store.select` with `take(1)` to `selectResolutionWidth` (in the example above). If the value is `undefined`, then I take it from the localStorage and dispatch it. That felt like a sweet solution - whenever I needed to store some state value to the local storage, all I needed is to use `StorableAction` instead of `Action` and name the `key`.

My questions are:

1. would you say it is a proper implementation of store effects, or am I bending the separation of concerns principal?
2. Now I've come to a scenario in which I need to store a value to the local storage that is actually not needed in the state (I only use it in one component). That brings up a conflict - should I use the same mechanism I created, or store to the local storage directly (which will cause a duplication, when `localStorage` is being managed both in state level and component level). What's better?

Thanks!